# Unable to extract collection names from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a mongodb (simple_demo) with an employee collection inside.

I am trying to connect to node JS and list the collections inside the simple_demo db.

I tried doing this but nothing came back. it just shows [].

Am wondering if I did anything wrong?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/simple_demo');
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('open', function () {
    console.log("connection ok");
    db.db.listCollections().toArray(function (err, names) {
        console.log(names); // [{ name: 'dbname.myCollection' }]
        module.exports.Collection = names;
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Chridam, sorry a typo? but i checked and its exactly the same spelling for listCollections for what i did.

Comment: I got confused with your variable naming, a db object and a connection object are totally different things

Answer (score 0):

Good day
Your code works. Check your database.